# Список пользователей на встрече Google Meet

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно вывести имена всех пользователей присутствующих на встрече **Google Meet**?

Какие библиотеки можно для этого использовать.

Comment: вроде бы нет апи у Google Meet. Только если пробовать парсить с помощью селениума

Comment: в python нет возможности парсинга с активного браузера? к примеру FireFox

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ с помощью селениума только

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнил задачу как и хотел.

Не уверен что код красиво выполнен, но свою работу выполняет.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException


class GoogleMeet(object):

    def Parse():

        meet_code = input('[?] Enter the meet code:\n>> ')
        meet_url = 'https://meet.google.com/' + meet_code

        driver = webdriver.Firefox()

        ################################ Обходим защиту гугл
        try:
            driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/identifier?client_id=717762328687-iludtf96g1hinl76e4lc1b9a82g457nn.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=profile%20email&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstackauth.com%2Fauth%2Foauth2%2Fgoogle&state=%7B%22sid%22%3A1%2C%22st%22%3A%2259%3A3%3ABBC%2C16%3A9b15b0994c6df9fc%2C10%3A1591711286%2C16%3A66b338ce162d6599%2Ca78a0c663f0beb12c0559379b61a9f5d62868c4fbd2f00e46a86ac26796507a1%22%2C%22cdl%22%3Anull%2C%22cid%22%3A%22717762328687-iludtf96g1hinl76e4lc1b9a82g457nn.apps.googleusercontent.com%22%2C%22k%22%3A%22Google%22%2C%22ses%22%3A%22921f8f04441041069683cc2377152422%22%7D&response_type=code&o2v=1&as=NCQvtBXI4prkLLDbn4Re0w&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow')
            sleep(2)
            email = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
            email.send_keys('login') # Ваш логин от гугл

            nextBtn = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
            nextBtn.click()

            sleep(2)
            passwd = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
            passwd.send_keys('PASSW') # Ваш пароль от гугл

            nextBtn = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext')
            nextBtn.click()

            print("[+] Login completed!\n")
        except:
            print("[-] Login error...")
            driver.close()
        ################################ Обходим защиту гугл

        driver.get(meet_url)
        sleep(5)
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div/div/div[7]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span')[0].click()

        sleep(3)
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div[7]/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span/span/div/div/span[1]')[0].click()

        sleep(1)
        users = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ZjFb7c')

        for i in range(0, len(users)):
            print(users[i].text)

        #driver.close()

GoogleMeet.Parse()
```

Comment: Хорошая работа :) Но я бы порекомендовал такой рефакторинг: `class GoogleMeet(object):` -> `class GoogleMeet:` (это излишнее указание), `Parse` -> `parse` (в питоне методы в нижнем регистре принято называть) и `range(0, len(users))` -> `range(len(users))`, а лучше вообще без индексов, т.е. `for x in users: print(x.text)`